# What is the material of the wing spar on the Mitsubishi MU-2?

Tags: wing, aircraft-structures, mitsubishi-mu-2

I read that the spar on Twin Commanders are made of steel. Is this also the case for the MU-2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *Jane's all the world aircraft* only the "main spar caps" are made "of heat-treated SAE 4000 series stell". For the MU-2 it gives 2025 and 7075 aluminium alloy as materials used for the wing.